# c++ maps and struct sockaddr_in copying values and using sendto

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, dictionary, sockaddr-in

okay, so I have a prob where when I try to get a struct sockaddr_in from my map, and use a tmp var to then send the stuct sockaddr_in through a socket using the method sendto.

```
map<string,struct sockaddr_in> userToAddrStrct;
```

after I call recvfrom i put the struct sockaddr into my map with a name as key.
then when I try to get that address again in another request i do.

```
string getUserOfCurrAddr()
{ 
    //recAddr is the (struct sockaddr_in) i initially use with recvfrom() method to receive address
    struct sockaddr_in* address = (struct sockaddr_in*)&recAddr;
    string aTmp = "";     
    map<string,struct sockaddr_in>::iterator i;
    for(i=userToAddrStrct.begin(); i != userToAddrStrct.end(); i++) {
        cout << "before checkEQ call\n";
        if(checkAddrEq(i->second,*address) == 0) {
            aTmp = i->first;
        }
    }
    return aTmp;
}
string username = getUserOfCurrAddr();
map<string, struct sockaddr_in>::iterator sockIt = userToAddrStrct.find(username);
```

and then I try to print out the contents in this map and I get a seg fault 11.  here is the code I used to print.

```
for(map<string,struct sockaddr_in>::iterator isu = userToAddrStrct.begin(); isu != userToAddrStrct.end(); isu++) {
        cout << "User: " << isu->first << " with address: " << stringAddr(isu->second) << " with port #: " << isu->second.sin_port <<"\n"; 
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated.  I am bad with c++ and may have a bad reference.

thanks to all!!!!

Comment: You get a seg fault where exactly?  Have you used a debugger?

Comment: no i haven't I just know I by using print statements it adds to the map when it shouldn't.  so when i print size for map it says 121424856313667 which is way big and it seg faults because thats an addrss probably

Comment: Where is the code that populates `recAddr` and `userToAddrStrct`?

Comment: Also, `getUserOfCurrAddr()` should exit as soon as it finds a match, and maybe also return the iterator so you don't have to call `find()` to search the `map` again. And when outputting `isu->second.sin_port`, you need to use `ntohs()`.